# How to change SharePoint extended web application's web.config file

Tags: sharepoint, web-config

Using the SharePoint API, how can I modify an extended webapp web.config file?

I have to do some changes in this file to specify the connection string, membershipprovider, etc... for using Forms Authentication.

Currently, I can change the "master" webapplication web.config file, but not the extended one.

> Edited
>
> I'm using Sp 2007. I'm already using SPWebConfigModification class to modify the parent webapp. Thoses modifications are propagated to the extended webapp. I have to change ONLY the extended one. But I don't find the way to do it.
>
> What I'm trying to achieve, is to program a little wizard that:
>
> - Shows a WebApp list so the user can select one
> - Extend that selected webapp to a different zone
> - Configure that extended zone to use Forms Authentication

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer form a blog.

> In your case , you need to write a Web Application scoped feature which after you provision your site using your C# app, it is deployed to the newly-provisioned site and in the receiver of the feature you inject the required web.config settings because in that context configuration API is obtainable , but again bear the following in mind:
>
> If you don’t use SPWebConfigModification class and either use ASP.NET 2.0 configuration API or your own mechanism , propagating changes across the farm is YOUR RESPONSIBILITY. If this happens on an standalone installation then you don;t need to be worried about this.

So it cannot be done externally. We have to do a feature in order to acheve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: look into the SPWebConfigModification class. I am assuming you're using SharePoint 2007. The best way to learn about this is to dig into open source projects:

Google code search: http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=spwebconfigmodification&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code
This project on CodePlex looks like it's one big SPWebConfigModification: http://www.codeplex.com/ajaxifymoss/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13360

Comment: According the SPWebConfigModification class, I'm already using it. I'm able to modify the "parent" webapp, but not the extended one.